# Remedy for a coffee hangover?

Tags: health, resting

Did you ever drink too much coffee during the week, and then on your day off you have this really tired feeling with a headache?  I call it a coffee-hangover.  It has nothing to do with alcohol just too much coffee.  I'm looking for a remedy to this, but not a remedy involving coffee; I'd prefer to save that for the week.

Comment: There is no problem in drinking moderate amounts of coffee every day (3 cups daily has plenty of health benefits). As suggested what you are experiencing is likely caffein withdrawal and the solution is to drink less coffee.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a caffeine "withdrawal" symptom.

According to [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/diet/caffeine-myths-and-facts)

> If you stop taking caffeine abruptly, you may have symptoms for a day
> or more, especially if you consume two or more cups of coffee a day.
> Symptoms of withdrawal from caffeine include:
>
> ```
> headache
> fatigue
> anxiety
> irritability
> depressed mood
> difficulty concentrating
> ```

It might be best to either reduce the coffee you drink during the week, or have coffee on the weekend too.

To avoid my headaches, I choose to have coffee on the weekend too.

Comment: does that mean that the coffee doesn't work as well come Monday and you then need more of it to have the same effect?

Comment: @leeand00, Not necessarily.  As you consistently consume caffeine you build a tolerance.  Varying the amount you consume, may help keep this tolerance from building as quickly.  Luckily, there are ways to “reset” your tolerance level.  There are caffeine detox products, or you can wean yourself by consuming less and less.

Answer (score 2):

I can also confirm that this situation is *caffeine withdrawal*.

IMHO, if you don't want to consume more caffeine in case of caffeine withdrawal, your best option is consuming **ibuprofen**.

You can validate my opinion also on the website located [here](https://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-headache).

The website states the solution (by leaning towards caffeine tablets as the end) as:

For those that are purposely detoxing from caffeine or for those that have consumed too much caffeine, we recommend the following.

- Take pain relievers like ibuprofen, acetaminophen, aspirin, and naproxen. (use only as directed)
- Drink plenty of water.
- Avoid medications, beverages, and foods with added caffeine.
- Sleep.
- Follow a step-by-step detoxing plan including caffeine tablets.

Comment: Wean Caffine?  Are those tablets cardboard?

Comment: @leeand00 Oops! I realised that I mentioned the brand by mistake. Let me correct it as this may look like spam. I prefer it to be seen only in the link. Btw, yes, they are tablets in a cardboard box.

Comment: Also useful in combo with ibuprofen is a couple of fiber tablets (and a cup of hot chocolate). Caffeine provides a metabolic boost which is missing in withdrawal.

Answer (score 1):

*Prevention* is better than cure for this one.

Understandably, you probably enjoy being charged during the week so you're always effective at everything you do. But it seems here that you need to reduce your intake so you do not experience this on weekends.

There are a few ways to do this without losing that all important energy during your weekday. One such method is to try drinking a [Bulletproof Coffee](https://blog.bulletproof.com/how-to-make-butter-coffee-bulletproof/). This is a technique used by many involving *Grass-fed Cow* Butter, which reportedly will increase the effects of caffeine making it last much longer. This is due to the butter making the caffeine release slowly in your system rather than all in one go. Other methods revolving around the same principle involve the use of *Extra Virgin Raw Coconut Oil* which also has similar effects to the butter, but then also contains essential dietary fats and provides your brain with whats known as [*Medium Chain Triglycerides*](https://www.alzdiscovery.org/cognitive-vitality/ratings/medium-chain-triglycerides) (MCT).

MCT is *converted to keytones in your body* which then is provided as energy to the brain. This is all good stuff to have in conjuntion with your coffee, as it's likely to help you reduce your intake. A raw tablespoon of it in the morning is also likely to have a [beneficial effect on your brain](http://www.naturallivingideas.com/eat-coconut-oil/) during the weekends too, so that may help with the headaches. An added bonus is that it whitens the teeth if held in the mouth for a short time before swallowing, which is also a good counter to the tooth staining effects of our favourite bev!

Comment: I recently heard about Bulletproof Coffee and how people are also adding other additives and supplements such as Omega-3 fatty acids and such to help increase awareness and alertness.  I have not personally tried it yet, but we have a coffee shop nearby that just started selling it and I plan on getting some soon.  However, everyone I know that has tried swears by it as their "go to" drink in the morning or when tired.

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of situation depends on the person and what is going on with that person and how/why they drink it.  Not how as in the French press vs drip, nor how as in what goes into it (cream and sugars), nor the type of roast or flavor and such.  Rather is this a first thing in the morning before you get dressed, or is it on your way to work, or something else.

A thought that I had that helps/helped me is to withhold the coffee for a bit.  I don't drink it to wake up or right away in the morning.  I drink it to enjoy things.
  I make sure I have a cup of water or two first, then I get my fresh cup of coffee.
I also typically try not to have it in the first 1.5 hours of waking up to make sure there is no dependency on it to wake up.
  I am a creature of habit as many are, but I will try to change it up once in a while.
I also make sure that after a certain hour I don't have anymore.  If I do, I don't make a habit of that and try to limit what I have that day or the next as a total.  It doesn't always work.
I also try to enjoy the coffee for the flavor, and not the caffeine rush.  If you need the caffeine rush, try Jolt Cola or Mountain Dew first thing.  Just kidding.

Last, I try but definitely not successful, but I read an article about drinking coffee and your circadian rhythm.  It makes sense and worth a shot.  But the recommendation is to try to drink coffee only when your cycle or rhythm is high to avoid that dependency during the lows.

Try these two articles to begin with.

https://gizmodo.com/the-scientifically-best-time-to-drink-coffee-1460030914

https://www.medicaldaily.com/caffeine-coffee-may-throw-circadian-rhythm-and-all-it-takes-one-double-espresso-353110

This all really helped me and I see many people that drink to drink caffeine or drink to wake up.  Keep all that in mind, and some of this might not be possible for everyone either.  Some may not have access to coffee after they leave their house, others it may be out of budget to get coffee elsewhere or through a different means (thus shifting the schedule and how / why you get coffee).
  It also helped me a little to switch to a French press and a hand grinder.  Even if I wanted it right away first thing in the morning, I need to boil water, grind the coffee, let it steep then plunge and enjoy...it's not a long or difficult process but it's not instant and helps me wait and be patient to get my fix.

Comment: I can also agree with what Keith has mentioned here. Drinking a coffee upon waking is apparently not good when comparing to waiting at least one hour before doing so. There are high levels of the stress hormone Cortisol in the brain upon waking, and drinking coffee first thing will allow it to be present at higher levels for the rest of the day. Drink your coffee once your Cortisol levels drop down and you might be able to also prevent headaches that way too. Less stress is always a good way to keep stress related symptoms at bay!

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced such symptoms, I overcome them by drinking fresh orange juice in warm water.

Comment: When your answer is subjective rather than objective, it may be better to add it as a comment instead of an answer.